# Скрипты не попадают в билд

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал разработку на *Unity3d*. Скрипты пишу на *С#*. Опыта программирования почти нет, начал изучать с нуля.

Написал небольшое приложение для своей пекарни в самой *Unity* все работает, но при создании `apk` файла в билд не попадают скрипты ни один. Все объекты типа кнопок и текста отображаются, но ничего не работает. Вскрыл запечатанный `apk` файл, скриптов не нашел. Версия *Unity* последняя, *SDK* обновлял и перезапускал, пробовал разные *API*, перековырял все настройки, перепробовал все советы, найденные в интернете. Ничего не помогло.

В *Edit - project settings - Script execution order* добавлял скрипты в разной последовательности.

В общем идеи закончились Кто может подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Comment: билд для PC работает нормально проблема только в Андроид версии

Answer (score 1):

Для начала точно уточни, что скриптов в apk нет.

1 вариант:
Почитай editor.log, открыть его можно в unity в console, там справа вверху значок, тыкаешь его и выбираешь open editor.log. В нем информация обо всем, что попадает в билд.
Он затирается при перезапуске unity, поэтому сначала сбилди, а потом открывай.

2 вариант:
Для этого найди в apk Assembly-CSharp.dll 
Декомпилируй с помощью jetbrains dotpeek или telerik justdecompile, внутри должны быть твои скрипты.

Если не найдешь скриптов таким образом, то возможно они в проекте лежат в зарезервированной папке типо Editor и не добавляются в билд( хотя это мало вероятно, т.к. пк версия работает). Вобще на сайте unity есть про них инфа.

А то что ничего не нажимается в android билде, возможно нет на сцене mobile input

Comment: В общем переписал все скрипты и добавил повторно, и вроде заработали, а то что не нажималась проблема действительно была в mobile input. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

При il2cpp компиляции неиспользуемые методы удаляются. Чтобы сохранить нужный метод используйте атрибут [Preserve]